# How do I get my object in pygame to move by holding the button?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame

I tried using something like this but it did not work.

```
while running:
keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()  #checking pressed keys
if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
    y1 -= 1
if keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
    y1 += 1
```

Here is the code I have at the moment. I tried using a different method because the above method did not work for me. It moves it one button tap at a time.

```
import pygame
spaceX = 100
spaceY = 100
pygame.init
black = (0,0,0)
size = (800, 800)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

def game(spaceX, spaceY):
    spaceship_file = 'spaceship.png'
    spaceship_image = pygame.image.load(spaceship_file)
    spaceship = pygame.transform.scale(spaceship_image, (30, 30))
    screen.fill(black)
    screen.blit(spaceship, (spaceX, spaceY))
    pygame.display.flip()

    while True:
        for event2 in pygame.event.get():
            if event2.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event2.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                spaceX2 = spaceX - 5
                game(spaceX2, spaceY)

            elif event2.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event2.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                spaceX2 = spaceX + 5
                game(spaceX2, spaceY)

game(spaceX, spaceY)
```

EDIT:

I have this code now. My object still only moves when I repeatedly tap the button and not when I hold it down.

```
def game(spaceX, spaceY):

    while True:
        screen.fill(black)
        screen.blit(spaceship, (spaceX, spaceY))
        pygame.display.flip()
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
                spaceX = spaceX - 5
                game(spaceX, spaceY)

            elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
                spaceX = spaceX + 5
                game(spaceX, spaceY)
```

Comment: Don't use recursive calls in your game loop. Python has set a limit to 1000 recursive calls before it raises an error. You can change this limit but a better way would be to put `screen.fill(black)`, `screen.blit(spaceship, (spaceX, spaceY))` and `pygame.display.flip()` in the `while True` loop. This way you also won't load in the image and scale it every time you move your spaceship.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "it did not work"? Because it should work perfectly fine. I've used the exact same code many times before.

Comment: I mean that I tried using pygame.key.get_pressed() instead of pygame.KEYDOWN before and it was not working.

Comment: I mean did you get an error, didn't it register when you pressed buttons, did it work but just not for what you were trying to accomplish, etc.? Because it should work if all logic is correct and it's one of the easiest ways to do what you're trying to do. Or you could introduce a velocity variable that you add onto the position every loop.

Comment: I edited my post with some edited code. I did get the pygame.key.get_pressed() to work but it still only moves 1 key tap at a time. No errors seem to pop up.

Comment: That's because you have it in the event loop. Move them outside and it should work.

Comment: Although you have to call some function from `pygame.event` for the game not to crash. Use `pygame.event.pump()` if you're not going to use the event loop. You can read about it more [here](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/pygame/5110/event-handling/18049/state-checking#t=201703091617398923333).

Comment: The event loop is only triggered when an event happen. So what it is saying in your code is "for every event that happens (whether it's a KEYDOWN, KEYUP, MOUSEBUTTONDOWN, VIDEORESIZE, etc) it should move the object if the arrow keys are pressed".

Comment: That worked! However, the program crashes after a while and it infinitely shows a bunch of errors. No error message but it tells me the line the error is in. Looks to be the line with game(spaceX, spaceY) after the keys are held down. After some time it stops working and an infinite amount of errors scroll by but with no specific error name.

Comment: Yes, as I wrote: you have to call some function from `pygame.event` for the game not to crash. I gave an easy fix to it in my answer below

Comment: And it can be error because of the recursion limit, as I explained in the comment at the top.

Comment: Yea sorry I guess I read through you previous replies too quickly. Thank you so much and I learned a lot!

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways to check for key input, either if they're in the event queue or checking their current state.

### Event queue

Keys are put into the event queue when they're pressed or realesed, so you cannot directly tell if a key is held or not. There are two ways around this:

1. Call `pygame.key.set_repeat(True)` before you enter the main loop. This will repeatedly put the KEYDOWN event into the event queue, as long as it's held.
2. Introduce a velocity variable. Set the velocity to some speed when the user press down the key, and set the velocity to 0 when the user lift the key.

For example:

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
            velocity_x = -5
        elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            velocity_x = 5
    elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
        if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
            velocity_x = 0
        elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            velocity_x = 0

position_x += velocity_x
```

### State checking

You get the current state of the keys by calling `pygame.key.get_pressed()`. You have to call one of the functions in `pygame.event` in order for pygame to do some required internal actions, so use `pygame.event.pump()` if you don't want to use the event queue. Your OS will think pygame has crashed if you don't, resulting in the game being unresponsive. Although, you usually want to handle the `pygame.QUIT` event, so the user can quit.

```
pygame.event.pump()
keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
    position_x -= 5
elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
    position_x += 5
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution to this problem would be to use `set_repeat` function

```
pygame.key.set_repeat(True)
```

This will generate multiple `KEYDOWN` events.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the keys to your pygame for loop. So it should look something like this...

```
while running:
for event in pygame.event.get():
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()  #checking pressed keys
        if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
        y1 -= 1

        if keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
        y1 += 1
```

Comment: pygame.key.get_pressed() should only be called once per loop. Not for every event in pygame.event.get().